# Running X on 3 of 4 Monitors and tail syslog on fourth

Tags: x11, multi-monitor, lubuntu

Is it possible to run the X-Server only on 3 of my 4 Monitors and use the last one for tail the syslog on a classic console? For me it is no option to tail it on a console inside X-Server.

System is current Lubuntu with NVidia Card

Comment: Have you tried configuring Xorg with `screen0` pointing to `nvidia0`, `screen1` using `nvidia1` and `screen2` using `nvidia2`, leaving `nvidia3` available as a standard console that you than configure as you see fit?